# tbButton update value database in yii

Tags: yii

newbie here.
How do I use tbButton to update one value in the database? Not even sure if this is how I should do it.

This is what I have so far.. in controller:

```
    public function activate()
{
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'type'=>'warning',
            'label'=>'Activate',
            'size'=>'small',
    ));
}
```

in view:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
                                        'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
                                        'dataProvider'=>$model->deactivate(),
                                        'columns'=>array(                                       array(
                                                        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
                                            ///blah///
                                                array(
                                                        'header'=>'Activate',
                                                        'value'=>array($this,'activate'),
                                                    ),
                                        )
                                    )); ?>
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trigger an ajax call to a controller, with that call you can pass the parameters, updated rows id, the field you want to be updated and so on.

then you can process it and give beck information regarding this call, and you can catch this info with the object who made the call

thats one way to do it :D